# Pegar uma cor HTML Conforme a IMAGEM

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como capturar uma cor em HTML porem essa cor tem que ser parecida com a imagem...

**EXEMPLO: (O FUNDO E PARECIDO COM A IMAGEM)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EXEMPLO 02: (REPAREM O FUNDO!)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer isso pra pegar a cor em *HTML*, assim posso usar essa cor aonde eu quiser... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui é exatamente o que você quer em PHP: https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor

Exemplo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\ColorExtractor\Client as ColorExtractor;

$client = new ColorExtractor;

$image = $client->loadPng('./some/image.png');

// Get the most used color hexadecimal codes from image.png
$palette = $image->extract();
```

Fonte: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290259/detect-main-colors-in-an-image-with-php)

Comment: Não sei oque fazer... coloco esse código no site, mas nada acontece..